# Can't find Application entry file './main.js' in electron build

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an electron app and I got this error when run `electron-builder build`.

```
Error: Application entry file "main.js" in the "/project/dist/release/mac/demo.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.
```

This is package.json. I have set the `main` to `dist/electron.js` but I don't understand why it keep saying `main.js` doesn't exist.

```
...
"main": "dist/electron.js",
"build": {
    "productName": "demo",
    "appId": "com.auspost.pos",
    "files": [
      "dist/",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json",
      "dist/electron.js"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist/release"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 220
        },
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 220,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis",
        "msi"
      ],
      "icon": "./electron/assets/icons/win/app.ico"
    },
    "publish": {
      "provider": "github"
    }
  },
...
"devDepencencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "^20.41.0",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.6.2",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally figure out that because the project has `electron-webpack` dependency which works as a base template for electron build configuration. There are some fields are defined there which get extended.

The fix for that is either remove `electron-webpack` from your project dependencies or use `electron-webpack` convention to manage your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue:

*Application entry file "index.js" in the ".....\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar" does not exist.*

The fix for me was to add

`main: "main.js"`

in the package.json of the generated app, so .\app\package.json.
Seems like without this electron-builder 21 (electron 6) is looking for a "index.js" file.

Answer (score 0):

If your main electron entry point file is called *electron.js* as you mentioned.

Then you 1st need to build your application in production:

```
ng build --configuration production
```

Now you should have your built code in your *dist* folder. (it can also be in the *dist/YourApp* folder and then you need to modify the path accordingly) In here you will have your *electron.js* file. You should verify that is it there.

Now in package.json you need to specify the path to *electron.js* file with the *main* parameter

In package.json:

```
"main": "dist/electron.js"
```

**OR** if you file is in dist/YourApp

```
"main": "dist/yourApp/electron.js"
```

Electron builder takes your built code and transforms it into an installer.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the error when selecting the production version of my entry file which was in a different folder than the source production file.

Here is the relevant config section that got my app to build:

```
 "build": {
    "files": [
      "electron-settings.json",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "../build/backend/min",
        "to": "app",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "from": "desktop/node_modules",
        "to": "node_modules"
      }
    ],
    "mac": {
      "extraResources": [
        {
          "from": "build/osx",
          "to": "app/build/osx"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```